# Google Maps - when clicked Marker doesn't show

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am trying to use the Google Map API- I've successfully managed to add an icon but when it is clicked nothing else happens...

This is my code:

```
function placeMarkerAtPoint(point)
{
    var marker = new GMarker(point,{icon: icon});

    GEvent.addListener(marker,"click",function() {

        marker.openInfoWindowHtml('here is some text');
    });

    map.addOverlay(marker);
}
```

When I run this in IE & click an Icon I see the not very useful javascript error: 'x' is null or not an object. I haven't even defined any variable called x ???

Thanks in advance for your your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you aren't instantiating an icon object (or not passing it into your placeMarkerAtPoint function).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that bit of code. 

I do this at the top of my js file like so:

var icon = new GIcon();
icon.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png";
icon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
icon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
icon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(10, 34);

Comment: Whops sorry just re-read your comment and now passed in the icon and its now working. 

Thank you!!